# Getting ValueError while fitting ANN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to fit ANN on Kaggle's Titanic dataset but getting ValueError. When I used RandomForest, there was no problem and when I am trying to use Artificial Neural Network, the code is throwing below error. Can you point out why I am getting the below error. I have pasted the code below

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    train_data = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/titanic/train.csv")
    test_data = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/titanic/test.csv")
    y = train_data["Survived"]
    y = np.array(y.values.tolist())


    features = ["Pclass", "Sex", "SibSp", "Parch", "Age", "Fare"]
    X = pd.get_dummies(train_data[features])
    X_test = pd.get_dummies(test_data[features])

    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    my_imputer = SimpleImputer()
    X = my_imputer.fit_transform(X)
    my_imputer = SimpleImputer()
    X_test = my_imputer.fit_transform(X_test)

    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    sc= StandardScaler()
    X=sc.fit_transform(X)
    X_test=sc.transform(X_test)

    import keras
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units=4, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation= 'relu', input_dim=6))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=4, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    #Fitting the ANN to the Training set
    classifier.fit(X, y, batch_size=10, epochs=100)
```

Error as below

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-30-f7e7c8ad52f1> in <module>
    ----> 1 classifier.fit(X, y, batch_size=10, epochs=100)

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs,     verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight,     initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers,         use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
       1152             sample_weight=sample_weight,
       1153             class_weight=class_weight,
    -> 1154             batch_size=batch_size)
       1155 
       1156         # Prepare validation data.

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y,     sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
        577             feed_input_shapes,
        578             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
    --> 579             exception_prefix='input')
        580 
        581         if y is not None:

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data,     names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
        143                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
        144                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
    --> 145                             str(data_shape))
        146     return data
        147 

    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_11_input to have shape (6,) but got array with         shape (7,)
```

I tried converting y variable to array but it still giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have put the wrong input shape in the first dense layer of your neural network. You have 7 columns, so you should have put `(7,)`. As a rule of thumb, you can put `X.shape[1]` for 1D data. So:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units=4, 
                     kernel_initializer='uniform', 
                     activation='relu', 
                     input_dim=X.shape[1]))
```

The reason why you ended up with 7 columns, and not 6, is because you one-hot encoded the `sex` variable with `pd.get_dummies`. Instead of `['male', 'female', 'female'...]`, you now have two columns: one for male, one for female. This is what `pd.get_dummies` does (see it on the right).

```
     Pclass  SibSp  Parch   Age     Fare  Sex_female  Sex_male
0         3      1      0  22.0   7.2500           0         1
1         1      1      0  38.0  71.2833           1         0
2         3      0      0  26.0   7.9250           1         0
3         1      1      0  35.0  53.1000           1         0
4         3      0      0  35.0   8.0500           0         1
..      ...    ...    ...   ...      ...         ...       ...
886       2      0      0  27.0  13.0000           0         1
887       1      0      0  19.0  30.0000           1         0
888       3      1      2   NaN  23.4500           1         0
889       1      0      0  26.0  30.0000           0         1
890       3      0      0  32.0   7.7500           0         1
```

It's generally easier to set `input_dim=X.shape[1]` because you don't have to set it manually, or even know how many columns there are. It's basically saying that the `input_dim` should be the number of columns of `X`, whatever it may be.

Comment: Thanks you so much Nicolas. It worked but I still do not understand the problem. Aren't there 6 inputs namely "Pclass", "Sex", "SibSp", "Parch", "Age", "Fare". Moreover, can you please elaborate on why the code worked by giving input_dim the value of X.shape[1]?

Comment: yes I added some comments in the answer. let me know if that answers your question

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for the help Nicolas. Just one last question. In my prediction variable, I am getting a 2D array (array([[0],[1],[1],...]]) but I want a 1D array. How can i do that?

Comment: try `classifier.predict_classes(X).ravel()` or `classifier.predict_classes(X).reshape(-1,)`

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I used flatten function.